# Disable Start Menu background blur

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, aero

I want to remove the blur effect pictured below from the start menu. I have already found solutions for window frames and the taskbar, yet the start menu remains unaffected. How would I go about doing this?

[image: Example depicting blur in start menu background]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to disable the transparency all you have to is right click on your desktop and click personalize. Go to window color. Then uncheck the "Enable Transparency" checkbox.

Comment: This is unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I want to disable/remove the blur so that the start menu looks like clear glass. Sorry if my question was vague.

Comment: IMHO, this will probably be either a file/registry hack or there's a workaround to enable this. I'm fine and capable with either.

Comment: Oh alright, I'd like up like clear glass themes or something

Comment: *look up is what I meant